# Classifying the "not applicable" category in document classification

Tags: python, classification, nltk, text-classification

Ive documents in the tuple format ("topic","doc"):-

```
('grain',
  'Thailand exported 84,960 tonnes of rice in the week ended February 24, '
  '689,038 tonnes of rice between the beginning of January and February 24, '
  'up from 556,874 tonnes during the same period last year. It has '
  'commitments to export another 658,999 tonnes this year. REUTER '),
 ('soybean',
  'The Tokyo Grain Exchange said it will raise the margin requirement on '
  'the spot and nearby month for U.S. And Chinese soybeans and red beans, '
  'effective March 2. Spot April U.S. Soybean contracts will increase to '
  '90,000 yen per 15 tonne lot from 70,000 now. Other months will stay '
  'will be set at 70,000 from March 2. The new margin for red bean spot '),.....
```

Ive taken only 10 topics for the classification task.

Now my problem is that there how do I classify anything apart from these 10 topics as "NA" (not from the 10 topics) ? Im using Naive_bayes right now. Is there any other classifier better suited to "NA" topics.? If yes then how do we set a threshold for "NA".

Comment: There is no way to do it within naive bayes classification unless you have other documents tagged with NA. You have to get some unrelated documents, add the 'NA' label to it and then retrain the classifier. There are ways to do multiple binary classification and then the documents that has no positive classes be treated as NA, but i think that's sub-optimal, gathering new data with NA tag and considering this as a multi-class classification might be easier to deal with.

Comment: @alvas Is there any classifier which outputs probability for a class ? That way maybe I can introduce a cutoff for a classes, which if not satisfied means "NA".

Comment: Go through `scikit-learn` and `gensim` documentations, you'll learn more about the different methods after going through the tutorials. Also try googling `machine learning coursera`, that'll help a little.